# Test web api with android application on a real device

Tags: android, iis-express

So i have a fully working ASP.NET webapi.
I'm trying to send http requsts to the server in my android application.
neither localhost:server_port nor myip:server_port works for me...
both my pc and my phone for testing are connected to the internet via the same wifi...

Comment: why are you even trying localhost:server_port on a real device?

Comment: @insomniac, for research purposes of course

Comment: Pretty basic,It would not work if you are trying to access a device using 'localhost' from any other device And if the ip is not working check the firewall is allowing it or not Or Make sure you are not running the webApi on the IIS Express instance but on the IIS instance

Comment: @insomniac, i was joking...i know it won't work. i just wrote that to make sure nobody will give this as an option by mistake...anyway, i think the webapi runs on IIS express instance. How can i run it on IIS insatnce instead?

Comment: If you are running it on IIS express ,bind it to your real ip like given in this page http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer

Comment: How to run it on IIS:Best way can be found with a google search, but as a quick solution, Enable IIS on your system by going to programs and features,and copy your WebApi buid to C:\inetpub folder and try